# VB.Net How To Free UP UI While Waiting For External Webservice Data to Load

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.net visual Studio 2019. We have designer forms to work with the UI. Not sure on the term for that.

Here's the scenario currently happening:

1) We have a webservice that gets called upon entering a certain screen, containing a DataGridView grid box.

2) For each row in this datagridview upon load, we are calling a third party webservice, because it provides information related to a single row that we need to populate.

3) This causes the application to hang for about 3 minutes when entering a screen with 300+ rows etc, as it will then loop through and call 300+ times before the data is populated and screen fully loads.

**Here's what I imagine happening in an ideal scenario**

We load that screen with the 300+ items quickly, leaving them blank. Then over time, they either start to fill in as they are retrieved, or it waits 3 plus minutes and then fills them in all at once , once they are all retrieved. While retaining function of the UI and it would just cancel if that screen was exited.

**Is there a way to implement that?**

Here's what I've looked into so far:

Await and Async. I messed around with this, and tested it, but could not get it to improve the speed. It still locks up whenever it has to go through those 300 calls.

Used this example: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2018/07/create-async-method.aspx

to implement Task.FromResult, this compiled and ran, but did not seem to do anything.

- read about task.run, do I need to look more into that?

? Asking the third party to offer an option webservice that takes a list, and sends a list back all at once. I would rather not do this if I can avoid it.

Anyone have any advice? Appreciate it. Thank you.

Please let me know for more details.

Comment: You wouldn't want to use `Task.FromResult`, they just used that for pedagogical reasons to show the transformation of a synchronous workflow into an asynchronous workflow.  You probably don't need to worry about `Task.Run` either.  I'd guess you're getting results from the web service using something like `System.Net.WebRequest`, which has an asynchronous method `GetResponseAsync`.  This has already done the hard work of being asynchronous, all you need to do is `Await` the result.

Comment: There are examples in MSDN of ways to aggregate multiple tasks.  For something like this, instead of `Await request.GetResponseAsync()`, you might do something like `TaskList(i) = request.GetResponseAsync()` and then `Await Task.WhenAll(TaskList)` (but make sure you respect any limitations on number of simultaneous requests imposed by the owner of the service!)